# Filter/Search different Lists with the same class with different headings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a script to Filter/Search different Lists with the same class.
If there is at least 1 search name matching, I need the script to display the headings of the list.
If there is no search name matching, I need the heading of the list to be hidden.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">    

<h1>List 1</h1>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>Adele</li>
    <li>Agnes</li>
</ul>

<h1>List 2</h1>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>Billy</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
</ul>

<h1>List 3</h1>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Jack</li>
</ul>



<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.querySelectorAll(".myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Example:
If I search for "l", the result must be:

```
<h1>List 1</h1>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>Adele</li>
</ul>

<h1>List 2</h1>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>Billy</li>
</ul>
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ul = document.querySelectorAll(".myUL");` This actually returns an array of the elements, so when you run `li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');` It's actually trying to reference an array, rather than an individual element.

If you loop through the values of ul and enclose the rest of the function in this loop, it works as expected.

See example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3v8mn2w/1/)

Comment: thank you! that worked! And is there a way to hide all the headings if there is no list matching?

Comment: @iolli Yeah, take a look at the JSFiddle again, I've updated it.

Comment: wow. I am looking forward to it! but I think I can not see the update..

Comment: thank you. so, you are hiding an elemet before.. is there a way to hide all headings instead? like h1 h2 h3 h3

I might have

<h1>List 3</h1>
<h2>subtitle</h2>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Jack</li>
</ul>

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: if(!show){
       h3.style.display = "none";
       h4.style.display = "none";
      } else {
       h3.style.display = "";
       h4.style.display = "";
      }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153962/discussion-between-jack-langstone-and-iolli).